# How to retain the value from an numericupdown after closing a form

Tags: c#, forms, save, numericupdown

I have the following question. I am using C# .NET, and I want to save a value in numericupdown box after I close my form. In my aplication I have in total 2 forms, so I want to save the value I enter in the second one, and after I open it again I want to see the last value. In my case the numericupdown value is empty after I open the second form again.

I was thinking about something like this:

```
namespace Project2
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            decimal a = numericUpDown1.Value;
            label2.Text = "N: " + a;
        }
    }
}
```

But is still empty after I open it again.

Comment: Where you want to use it when you open `Form2` next time. Can you show us that code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a class which provides set/get for a NumericUpDown control in this case using the following.

```
public sealed class Setting
{
    private static readonly Lazy<Setting> Lazy = 
        new Lazy<Setting>(() => new Setting());
    public static Setting Instance => Lazy.Value;
    public decimal NumericUpDownValue { get; set; }
}
```

In the child form, OnShown set Value property to Settings.NumericUpDownValue then OnClosing remember the value.

```
public partial class ChildForm : Form
{
    public ChildForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Shown += (sender, args) => 
            numericUpDown1.DataBindings.Add("Value", Setting.Instance, 
                nameof(Setting.NumericUpDownValue));

        Closing += (sender, args) => 
            Setting.Instance.NumericUpDownValue = numericUpDown1.Value;
    }
}
```

The code above, specifically Settings class is known as the Singleton Pattern which you can learn more about in [Implementing the Singleton Pattern in C#](https://csharpindepth.com/articles/singleton).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`static variable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/static-classes-and-static-class-members#static-members) to store last updated value and with the reference of class name you can use it where ever you want.

> [From MSDN:](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/static-classes-and-static-class-members#static-members) Two common uses of static fields are to keep a count of the number of
> objects that have been instantiated, or **to store a value that must
> be shared among all instances.**

Like,

```
namespace Project2
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        public static decimal lastNumericUpDownValue = 0;  
        public Form2()
        {
            //For example: thiw will print lastest saved Numeric updown value.
            //For the first time, it will print 0
            Console.WriteLine(Form2.lastNumericUpDownValue);
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Assign value to lastNumericUpDownValue variable. Look at how it is used.
            Form2.lastNumericUpDownValue = numericUpDown1.Value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please watch my update comment.